# Find the constant term in the Fourier series for $f$?

Tags: fourier-series

Let $f(x)$ be the function on `[−3, 3]` which is graphed below,
[image]

Find the constant term in the Fourier series for $f$?

$$\frac{a_{0}}{2}=\frac{1}{2L}\int^{L}_{-L}{f(x)}dx=\frac{1}{2\times3}\int^{3}_{-3}{f(x)}dx=\frac{1}{2\times3}\bigg[\int^{0}_{-3}{f(x)}dx+\int^{3}_{0}{f(x)}dx\bigg]$$

From here on, I have no idea where to go

Comment: 30+ months on the site and you post... this?

Comment: @Did sometimes simple things makes life difficult.

Comment: The level of the question is offtopic, what was pointed was the lack of context of the first version of your question. // Re "your try", you are confusing the values of $f$ and of its primitive $F$.

Comment: @Did I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: @Did any hint you can suggest?

Comment: Perform the integral separately on each of the four intervals where $f$ is linear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39424/discussion-between-mmm-and-did).

Comment: Which numerical values did you find for these four integrals?

Comment: -8/2, -1/2, 1/2, 8/2

Comment: For example, on (0,1) the function is always greater than 3, and (0,1) has length 1 but you find that the integral of the function on (0,1) is 1/2? This is absurd, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing calculations, it is  useful to grasp their  interpretation and get intuition on the result.

The constant term in the Fourier series is simply the average value of the function over one period. Here, your function est antisymmetric around $(0,2.5)$. So the respective areas above and below $2.5$ compensate. I guess $5/2$ could be the desired result. You now perform the actual computations. You can compute integrals, and you can do geometry: draw vertical lines below discontinuities $(-3,-1,0,1,3)$, and [sum areas of trapezoids](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/vol1/area_trapezoid.html).

All results should match.

A graphical explanation: for the average

[image: Average]

The area between the black and the  blue curve are the same, except for the sign. So the area of the blue curve is the same as that of the black curve, which is easy to compute.

If you really want to compute areas with trapezoids, here are four of them. The first on the left has $2\times 1$ (bottom rectangle)  plus $ 2\times 2/2$ (top triangle. Finally, from left to right, you add four trapezoids and  you get $4+1.5+3.5+6=15$. The average value is thus $15/(3-(-3))=2.5$.

[image: Trapezoids]